# Wait for animation end

Tags: android, animation

I've an activity that loads the resources and shows the message "Please wait, loading", and when all resources are loader, the textview changes to "Ready" and change the views of the activity. The problem is that I want to wait for the animation end, but the views are removed even before they start. How can I wait for that?

```
        tview1.startAnimation(desvanecer); tview2.startAnimation(desvanecer);

        tview1.setText(R.string.ready); 
        tview2.setText(R.string.launcher_continue);

        tview1.startAnimation(aparecer);
        tview2.startAnimation(aparecer);

        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.launcher_layout);

        screen = new Screen(context);

        thread = new Thread(screen);

        layout.removeAllViews();

        layout.addView(screen);

        thread.start();
```

Comment: I can't see that the animation has any time to run here. What happens between the start of 'desvanecer' and 'aparecer'? Why do you delete all views, including them that are animated? It might help if you add comments to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform your removals at the end of the animation by using an animation listener and doing them onAnimationEnd

```
desvanecer.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                 //REMOVAL OR OTHER CODE HERE
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an AnimationListener and implement the onAnimationEnd method. But have a look at my comment and the doubts I have about your code.